# IntelliJ External Libraries Compile Time Errors

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, sbt

I added an external library to my java project for fedmsg. I had my code compiling and working great. I needed something extra from the fedmsg class so I forked their repository and opened a pull request and the development got up stream.

Back to IntelliJ, I rebuilt the doc, src, and class .jar for the updated code and re-imported it back into IntelliJ. IntelliJ shows no errors and even autocompletes my code as seen here: [image]

However, when I compile my code in IntelliJ AND the atlassian SDK, I get this error:

> Error:(49, 19) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   method disconnect()
>     location: variable fedmsg of type org.fedoraproject.fedmsg.FedmsgConnection

The disconnect method is in the FedmsgConnection class, and that class exists as an external library where the error says it does:

[image]

Any idea what's going on? NOTE: When I compile the fedmsg-java .jars with sbt, there are obviously no errors.

EDIT: Another weird thing, if you "Search by symbol" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in IntelliJ), I can type "disconnect()" and the method from the fedmsg class shows up.

Comment: Did you change the version of the associated dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: @yole The version didn't change. I had to manually reimport the .class files into my file structure via copying and pasting them into the right spots. I must be doing something wrong when I'm importing a 3rd party .jar not tracked by maven.

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Tried that a long with the multiple other "reset" functionalities that IntelliJ has and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Do IntelliJ and SBT have the same target where the .class files go, or are there two different locations? Having the only place you find classes (e.g. target/scala-2.11/classes) would seem the cleanest way to have SBT and IntelliJ cooperating - with SBT being the 'master'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed by manually importing (copying and pasting) the *.class files from the third party library SBT project (that were created by "sbt compile"), to where IntelliJ expects them to be, which is:

"(project root)\classes"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that like me you have the Scala plugin but no others. If your SBT project is good and your IDEA project is confused then delete the '.idea' directory. Thus you will end up with just an SBT project. From IntelliJ IDEA you can now create the project again from scratch. To do this File -> Open and navigate to the SBT icon for your project. The SBT icon is three blue horizontal lines (hamburger bun). Probably you can leave all the settings as they are, just check the right JDK has been picked up.

I don't tend to compile within IntelliJ, but use `~package` from SBT. However I do sometimes need to refresh the IntelliJ project whenever the `build.sbt` file has changed - something which IntelliJ informs you about if you go to the `build.sbt` file. For refreshing the project to work I need to make sure that the `JVM options` are lower than the defaults. Currently working for me is to have a 'Maximum heap size, MB' of `568` and 'VM parameters' of `-XX:MaxPermSize=334M`. Another problem I have had during refreshing is with comments in the `build.sbt` - I have had to strip them out to avoid an IntelliJ stack trace.

Whenever all the jar dependencies are correct but IntelliJ won't compile a project - evidenced by the syntax highlighting being all wrong, then just start over with IntelliJ. So far I have needed to do this on a fairly regular basis.

Comment: I must being explaining things poorly. I have an atlassian project that is what I imported into IntelliJ. I have a third party library (not found on maven), that compiles with SBT. The .jars that it compiles to I imported into IntelliJ using the "Project Structure -> Libraries -> +" procedure. For some reason it doesn't also look for the class files and import those as well. Probably because it's an SBT project and not something that it expected, I'm guessing.

Comment: I don't know what an Atlassian project is I'm afraid. The .class files are already in the jar file so that should be enough. Generally speaking I find it is good to give IntelliJ as little responsibility as possible and leave SBT in control. I find it is good not to use functions such as the importing libraries procedure you mention. In my experience there is no need to do it, and it seems to be the cause of your problem. If the jar files you need are in your build.sbt file that should be enough.